# Fom browser a csv file from URL (url 1) can be downloaded only if another URL of main page (url) is open in browser. How to implement in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, url, browser

If the url https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-announcements  is open in a tab of browser, I can download the CSV file using another  url https://www.nseindia.com/api/corporate-announcements?index=equities&from_date=14-01-2022&to_date=20-01-2022&csv=true from another Tab in same browser. Else Not and it says "resource not found". How can I implement it in python using pandas.

Comment: it can use two methods to block it - (1) cookies, (2) javascript. It can check if browser has cookies and it would need to use `requests` to send requests with cookies to read data and later send this data to pandas. If it uses JavaScript then it would need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript because `pandas` and even `requests` can't run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page uses Cookies to check if file was opened from first page.

You will have to use `requests` and `Session` to get first page and cookies, next use `requests` and `Session` (with cookies from previous request) to get file `csv`, and finally you will have to send data to `pandas` using `io` which simulate file in memory.

BTW: it seems it sends file with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (`Byte Order Mark`) so I read bytes data from `r.content` instead of text data from `r.text` and `pandas` will skip `BOM`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

# --- create Session with User-Agent from real browser ---

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

# --- get first page to get cookies --- 

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-announcements'
r = s.get(url)

# --- get file ---

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/corporate-announcements?index=equities&from_date=14-01-2022&to_date=20-01-2022&csv=true'
r = s.get(url)

print(r.text[:100])  # code `ï»¿` at the beginning means BOM
                     # so I will use `r.content` instead of `r.text`

# --- read file from memory ---

#df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.text))   # it doesn't remove BOM
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(r.content))  # it removes BOM

# --- show it ---

print(df.head())
```

Result:

```
ï»¿"SYMBOL","COMPANY NAME","SUBJECT","DETAILS","BROADCAST DATE/TIME","RECEIPT","DISSEMINATION","DIFF


      SYMBOL  ... DIFFERENCE
0  TATAELXSI  ...   00:00:08
1       RIIL  ...   00:00:10
2       ERIS  ...   00:00:06
3       RIIL  ...   00:00:09
4  INGERRAND  ...   00:00:09

[5 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: very nicely explained.  
I want to write to csv file. I gives errors when i use 
open('C:\\dropbox\\apy\\temp1.csv', "w") as f:
    df.to_csv(f, index=False)  
    f.close()

Comment: you don't need `open()` and `close()` but  `df.to_csv('C:\\dropbox\\apy\\temp1.csv', index=False)`. But without full error message I can't say what is real problem. Better create new question on new page.

Comment: There is one field "DETAILS" which is throwing errors when writing to a text or csv file. The error is something like UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 10884-10885: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: done,  all that was needed was encoding='utf-8' when opening the file for a write

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. I want to accept this solution. Where Please ?